# Error on Declaring Double

Tags: java

I have the code:

```
double myVar = 4000000;
```

However java returns a value saying: "Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token"

Suggestions?

Cheers!

Full code:

```
public class FibonacciSum {

double a = 1;
double b = 1;

double sum = 0;
double evenSum = 0;

double target = 4000000; 

while(sum < target) {

    sum = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = sum;

    if(sum % 2 == 0)
        evenSum += sum;

}

System.out.println(evenSum);

}
```

Comment: Show more code (the lines before and afer that one).

Comment: The line you are showing and the error you are saying is different

Comment: use `double target = 4000000.0;`

Comment: You are missing a **method** definition.

Comment: You can't just have a while loop or other expression statements directly in the body of a class.

Comment: @plsgogame - not needed. Java is happy to cast to **a larger type**.

Answer (score 2):

What is the code context?

Most likely, you have put this line into an inappropriate place, for example *not* into a method. That line should live in a method or at least a class definition.

Standalone, this is not valid Java! You probably can use it in bean shell, though.

**Update after edit: Your code is missing a *method*!**

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a method body. You are trying to run code directly in the class.

Wrap the code inside a main method:

```
public class FibonacciSum {

    public static void main(String...args) {
        double a = 1;
        double b = 1;

        double sum = 0;
        double evenSum = 0;

        double target = 4000000; 

        while(sum < target) {

            sum = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = sum;

           if(sum % 2 == 0)
           evenSum += sum;

        }

        System.out.println(evenSum);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to make a class just put this inside of your main method.

```
public class FibonacciSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 1;
        double b = 1;
        double sum = 0;
        double evenSum = 0;
        double target = 4000000; 
        while(sum < target) {
            sum = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = sum;
            if(sum % 2 == 0)
                evenSum += sum;
        }
        System.out.println(evenSum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code

```
class Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double myVar = 4000000;
        System.out.println(myVar);
    }
}
```

the output is 4000000.0